# Compiler like to point bugs for Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am somewhat of a beginner with JS but it occured to me that it would be nice to have a compiler like thingy that shows where the errors are (though its an interpreted language) - i am currently using Webstorm without any customizations but as far as i can tell its not pointing to obvious errors. For example if i have an opening brace and not a closing brace; or an extra closing brace - a compiler would point to that fact; i am sure JS has some eqivalent way - isnt there?

```
  <script>
        var switchDirection = false;

        function doAnimation(){
            var divAdvert = document.getElementById("divAdvert");
            var currentLeft = divAdvert.offsetLeft;
            var newLocation;

            if(!switchDirection) {
                newLocation = currentLeft + 2;

                if (currentLeft >= 400) {
                    switchDirection = true;
                }
            }else{
                    newLocation = currentLeft -2;

                    if(currentleft <=0){
                        switchDirection = false;
                    }
            }
                divAdvert.style.left = newLocation + "px";
        }
        }  // extra closing brace hard to find; why isnt there a compiler like thing to show where errors are for JS?
```

Comment: Use a linter; JSHINT, JSLINT and ESLINT are examples. There is probably a plugin for Webstorm.

Comment: Interpreters point out errors the same way compilers do, you just have to run your code for them to do it.

Comment: Use your browser's built-in dev tools

Comment: Run your code in any modern browser with its Dev tools open - usually accessible by pressing F12. Most JavaScript engines will actually *compile* each function as it is encountered - Firefox and Edge make bytecode, Chrome actually produces x86 - and if it notices that it has trouble doing that, such as when the function doesn't actually end, then it will log a syntax error.

Comment: Seconding @Xotic750 - from personal experience, I'd order the linters like this: ESLint > JSHint >>> JSLint. The first two are not _too_ different at a beginner level, to be honest - they both ship with reasonable default settings. ESLint happens to be easier to configure, hence the first place. JSLint is a bit more strict in some departments where it doesn't need to. There is also JSCS which is for codestyle checking, e.g., having `{` in the same line as `if` statements and loops or on a new line. Finally, you can add `"use strict";` to you code which will enable extra checks in the parser.

Comment: As you pointed out, JS is not a compiled language, so there is no compiler to catch your errors during development.  If you are using Visual Studio, you can use an extension that helps with that: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ede12aa8-0f80-4e6f-b15c-7a8b3499370e

Comment: I use PhpStorm, which is the Mac version of WebStorm. It will find many syntax errors. It's better for PHP than Javascript, but it does it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of your options:

- NodeJS; it's basically JavaScript for servers (rather than webpages), and can be run in a CLI environment, which will show you errors.
- The browser console will spit out errors in your code when you try to run in.
- Linters such as JSHint and JSLint will point out problems similar to browser consoles, and will also give you code style tips.
- IDE plugins. I'm sure if an IDE doesn't come out of the box with support for things like this, you can find a plugin for it (try looking for an automatic linter plugin).

Comment: yes; now i see. It was pointing to these problems in the console window.

Good to know about the other options.